# mysql datadir on USB drive / mysql multiple instance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, usb, multiple-instances

I followed many post showing how to run a second mysql instance to point to a different datadir, and with this example, it works fine :

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql2
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql2/
mkdir /var/log/mysql2
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql2
cp -R /etc/mysql/ /etc/mysql2

cd /etc/mysql2/
sed -i 's/3306/3307/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.sock/mysqld2.sock/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/mysqld.pid/mysqld2.pid/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/lib\/mysql/var\/lib\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
sed -i 's/var\/log\/mysql/var\/log\/mysql2/g' my.cnf
```

Editing apparmor mysql file (i'm on ubuntu)

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2/

mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql2/my.cnf &
```

The code above works well, but then if i replace /var/lib/mysql2 with a location pointing to an external usb drive (/media/marcel/mysql), if fails at the mysql_install_db step.

Do someone know why and how to correct this ? Is it impossible to install a datadir on an external drive ??

Thanks for your help

Julien

addition :

I found on a forum that the same error seemed to be corrected on gentoo by manipulating USE flags ??

```
Could you check if you have max-idx-128 enabled in your USE flags? I just re-emerged mysql-5.1.50 without that flag and it doesn't crash anymore.
```

I don't really know what USE flags are, but it seems to be related to compilation, is it ?

Comment: Why do you need a mysql datadir on USB drive at all?

Comment: @jtextori, what error did you get, could you please put here messages from error.log?

Comment: @Hast, because the lack of space on the main drive, for example.

Comment: @Hast, I work in 3 different places, and I use genomics databases which are huge. I don't have enough place on my laptop drive, so I thought I could install the database on a usb diskdrive, and take it with me, and only configure a second instance of mysql server on each computer ?

Comment: @ravnur, it is a permission issue. I checked several times the apparmor file to see if i missed something, but as i said, the strange thing is that it works perfectly with a directory on the hard drive, and not on the usb drive ? error.log says : ERROR: 1  Can't create/write to file '/media/marcel/ensembl/mysql/mysql/db.MYI' (Errcode: 13)
121101 19:23:26 [ERROR] Aborting. Do you know if i can look somewhere else ?

Comment: 1. kill apparmor (you can restore it lately) 2. `ls -l /media/marcel/ensembl/mysql/mysql/` who is the owner: mysql.mysql? Did mysql have a permissions to write there?

Comment: yes mysql is owner. I tried with various chmod configurations, including a+rwx (777) mode ! no way ... And with or without apparmor does not change anything (i did it via "service apparmor stop", right ?)